# Python writing in word files with docx library

Tags: python, docx

I installed the docx library and import it with `import docx`. But wherever I look for documentation or information about this library, I see that people use `doc = docx.Document()` to call the class, but in the library that I installed, there is no class named `Document`. I'm confused, there are some other functions but I don't know how to use them, does anyone know how this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing python-docx and docx packages. If you install python-docx with

```
pip install python-docx
```

you will find `Document` method as shown in the image.

[image]